# ASP.NET Core 6.0 with SPA, handle InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, reactjs, single-page-application, asp.net-core-6.0, webview2

I'm trying to create a small application using ASP.NET Core 6.0 with ReactJS and WebView2 for learning purposes.
I `published` and it is running without problem, if I will run it by itself or from CMD. As soon as I'm trying to run it using another application it fails `most of the time` and gives me this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware
> could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not
> found, and no other middleware handled the request.
> Your application is running in Production mode, so make sure it has
> been published, or that you have built your SPA manually.
> Alternatively you may wish to switch to the Development environment.
>
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__1(HttpContext
> context, RequestDelegate next)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_1.b__1(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(HttpContext
> context, RequestDelegate next)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_1.b__1(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

I tried  building with `Debug`, `Production`, `Any CPU`, `x86`, `x64`. Tried also:

```
public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseRootRewrite(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        var socks = "/sockjs-node";

        builder.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (!HttpMethods.IsGet(context.Request.Method) && !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(socks))
            {
                if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                    context.Response.CompleteAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    return;
                }
            }
            
           await next();
        });

        return builder;
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
public class Startup() {
    ...
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
        app.UseRootRewrite();
        app.UseSpa(config => {});
    }
}
```

Many other suggestions from all over the internet but it seems I couldn't find any solution for my application.

Maybe someone can help in handling this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days of struggling, I found out what was wrong with my application. Since I was running it from the parent application, the child application somehow acquired the parent application's path, and of course, in the parent application's folder, there was no `ClientApp/build` directory. Instead of putting the `ClientApp/build` folder in the parent application's directory, I change the path inside the child application's source like this:

AddSpaStaticFiles

```
// In production, the React files will be served from this directory
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "Parent-dir/Child-dir/ClientApp/build";
    Console.WriteLine(configuration.RootPath);
});
```

UseSpa

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "Parent-dir/Child-dir/ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

In the future, I will try to make this better but for now, this solved my problem.